# NPM: How to link 2 package with same name but different version?

Tags: node.js, npm, bower, yarnpkg

I wanna develop **2 versions** of package with **same name**, but **different versions**:

first

```
// package.json
{
  "name":"mypackage",
  "version": "1.0.0-base"
}
```

second

```
// package.json
{
  "name":"mypackage",
  "version": "2.0.0-next"
}
```

Now I wanna in two different projects do:

`npm link <path to mypackage@1.0.0-base>`

or

`npm link <path to mypackage@2.0.0-next>`

For now , when I do that, last linked package "replace"
the every linked module with name **mypackage** in previous linked projects.

I know that *npm* has "global space" for linking... but is there any way to get around this ?

Answer (score 0):

https://github.com/ORESoftware/npm-link-up may be the solution for you. It looks like it uses actual symlinks, rather than the NPM global space. I have not used it yet (honestly I was looking into the same problem but haven't gotten around to trying this as a solution yet).

Let me know if this solves your problem!

(https://github.com/ORESoftware/npm-link-up/blob/dev/docs/in-detail.md describes it as not using global space)